# How to modify code written in InitializeComponent method (WinForms Designer generated code)?

Tags: c#, winforms, generated-code, initializecomponent

I'm a WPF developer and have to perform some task in WinForms (I'm a total newbie of WinForms).

Unlike in WPF, I've noticed that the InitializeComponent method in WinForms is generated by the Windows Form Designer, and obviously I can't modify the code written in this method manually as it might just be overridden upon code regeneration.

Let's say I wish to change the following line in the InitializeComponent of WinForms
From:

```
this.myBtn.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomCenter;
```

To:

```
this.myBtn.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

What is the correct way of doing so? I haven't found any custom code in the codebase that enforces this BottomCenter value? Where is this value coming from? Is it a default value in WinForms?

I've searched the web and encountered similar questions, such as:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92ab4ea6-c7c8-44cb-91e7-e91c4f77accd/how-to-modify-windows-form-designer-generated-code-in-initializecomponent-method-programmitically?forum=winforms

in which it is suggested to implement a custom CodeDomSerializer on the control. Is it the right approach for doing such a simple thing? I just want to change a simple ImageAlign property.

Comment: That's simply the value of a Property of a Control. You can change that value in the Form Designer (as in WPF). If you want to change it - after the initialization - to another value, for some reason, just add that line of code after the `InitializeComponent()` call in the code file of your Form (e.g., `Form1.cs`). -- @jdweng The `Designer.cs` file IS overwritten (what's in the `InitializeComponent()` method and the Fields declarations) each time you change something and compile.

Comment: If you are using VS… then, somewhat similar to WPF, if you click on the “Button” control in the designer to “select” it, then, a “properties” window opens on the right. If you do this, then you will see that the button has an `ImageAlign` property which you can change. This will change the code in the “designer.cs” file.

Comment: A CodeDomSerializer can be used, of course, if you have a Custom Control or UserControl and you want to generate specific serialization that supersedes or overrides what the Designer *could* generate on its own (because you want, for example, create a specific behavior determined by variable run-time settings, create a custom designer, create and assign property values or generate and configure objects that follow a logic that doesn't necessarily derive from design-time values)

Comment: Thank you for your help, everyone.

@jdweng "Usually the best method to change the designer default settings is to create a form load method and make changes in the form load method which gets called the first time the form is used. ": I think I would implement this approach, as I need to differentiate this property value between .Net6 and earlier versions (instead of changing the designer's value). And besides, I already see I have a Load method hooked, so that's great. If you wish, post your reply as an answer and I'll accept it.

A big thanks to everyone else who tried to help.

Comment: It is not the default, if it were you wouldn't see the statement.  Changing it is easy, select the button in the designer, look in the Properties window and change the ImageAlign property.